How to Use a Custom Overlay container for a specific Angular MatDialog Component
Is it possible to have a component that's opened with MatDialog.open to use a different overlay main container that is not .cdk-overlay-container?
I've defined this CustomOverlayContainer class:
import { OverlayContainer } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class CustomOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
    protected override _createContainer(): void {
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.classList.add("my-custom-overlay-container");
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        this._containerElement = container;
    }
}

and if I add it as a provider to AppModule:
{ provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CustomOverlayContainer },
it works globally, but I want to specifically have CustomOverlayContainer be used in the case of a FullScreenSupplyChainDialog which I open like this:
this.dialog.open(FullScreenSupplyChainDialog, options)
I know I can add a panelClass option, but that's not enough in my use case.
If I add { provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CustomOverlayContainer }, to FullScreenSupplyChainDialog or even the parent component, nothing changes, but I'm not sure why

Does this help you?

@Pieterjan unfortunately it didn't work. I tested with:
providers: [{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'customClass' } }]
it seems MatDialogConfig doesn't have a overlayPanelClass property at all

It is panelClass not overlayPanelClass. NOTE: Rememeber that, as the overlay is created "outside" the app, The class should be defined in the styles.scss not in the component.css

@Eliseo panelClass is a child of .cdk-overlay-container, it doesn't replace it. I don't want to use cdk-overlay-container for a specific component (it's ok for others)
